# Visual Studio 2013 Start button gone

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have question about VS2013. It's my first day with VS, and my Start button is gone. Any kind of layout or settings reset doesn't help. Here is screenshot with what replaced Start button (it's attach button)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to create or open a project in order to have something to run.